# UITabBar MoreViewController image in UITableView disappears after programmatically selecting it

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I'm trying to select one of my UINavigationControllers in the UITabBar.viewControllers array.

I previously tried it with setting the UITabbarController.selectedIndex, but the Apple documentation says:
*"To select the More navigation controller itself, you must change the value of the selectedViewController property instead."*

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
UINavigationController *navController = [appDelegate.objTabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:5];
[appDelegate.objTabBarController setSelectedViewController:navController];
```

Doing so is fine but when I change back to the MoreViewController's list view, the icon on the left side is gone and won't come back.

Everything ok, when selecting it with the finger.

[image: Selecting is fine]

Bug when selecting programmatically -> image is gone

[image: Per Code Step 1]
[image: Per Code Step 2]
[image: Per Code Step 3]

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Best regards,
Steve

Comment: shouldn't it be `objectAtIndex:4`?

Comment: Which image is gone? Its difficult for me to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Selecting the More Navigation Controller**

To select the moreNavigationController, you must set the `selectedViewController`:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController;
```

The reason for that is simple: The moreNavigationController is not inside the `viewControllers` of the tab bar controller, so it can't be selected by index.

To select one of the "more" controllers directly, you can either set the `selectedViewController` property:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = viewController5;
```

Or you can set the `selectedIndex`:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 5;
```

**Fixing the Disappearing Tab Bar Image**

The disappearing tab bar image is caused by using a navigation controller (for the settings) inside a navigation controller (the `moreNavigationController` generated by the tab bar controller). To fix it, there are two solutions:

1. Don't add navigation controllers for the more section, but add the controllers directly. The controller structure would look like this, assuming the controllers in all tabs need navigation:

   ```
   tabBarController
   + navigationController
     + viewController0
   + navigationController
     + viewController1
   + navigationController
     + viewController2
   + navigationController
     + viewController3
   + viewController4
   + viewController5
   ```
2. Set the `tabBarItem` of the settings controller on its navigation controller (you only need to do this once):

   ```
   UINavigationController *settingsNavigationController = [appDelegate.objTabBarController objectAtIndex:5];
   UIViewController *settingsRootController = settingsNavigationController.viewControllers[0];
   settingsNavigationController.tabBarItem = settingsRootController.tabBarItem;
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was having a similar problem, where after pressing the back button on one of my tabs to go back to the moreNavigationController, the image for that tab would momentarily be blank. I've spent a week on and off trying to figure it out and this simple change (the first solution you posted) finally fixed it.

Comment: @Sam Glad to hear this still works. The workaround dates back to the time where iOS was named iPhone OS …

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem.  It seems that the navigation controller was somehow losing track of the view controller.  In my case, the navigation controller whose image was disappearing was at index 7 in the tabBarController.  The navigation controller was supposed to contain a viewController of class SettingsViewController.  But sometimes it lost it.

To fix it, I had to add code to two classes -- the app delegate and SettingsViewController.  In the app delegate:

```
-(void) fixSettingsNavigationController {
    UITabBarController* tab = self.tabBarController;
    NSArray* vcs = tab.viewControllers;
    NSInteger nVCs = vcs.count;
    if (nVCs > 7) {
        UIViewController* settingsContainer = vcs[7];
        UINavigationController* settingsContainerNav = (UINavigationController*)settingsContainer;
        if ([settingsContainerNav isKindOfClass: [UINavigationController class]]) {
            NSArray* settingsNavVCs = settingsContainerNav.viewControllers;
            NSInteger count = settingsNavVCs.count;
            SettingsViewController* svc = self.settingsViewController;
            if (!count) {
                  //  The container navigation controller has lost track of the settings view controller.
                  settingsContainerNav.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:svc];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in SettingsViewController:

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    MyAppDelegate* appDel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDel fixSettingsNavigationController];
    [super viewWillDisappear: animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran to the very similar situation, where I want to select a View controller inside MoreViewController programmatically.

As you said in your question, apple don't allow selecting a view controller that is inside MoreViewController (Or not visible in tabbar).

In my case, I don't need default "More" features of reordering tabs in tabbar.

So, I did following things

1. Created a UITableViewControlelr as my 5th tab, set its Title to more and custom image (Similar to default more image).
2. In my UITableViewController I listed items that corresponds to ViewControllers. Tapping on which show respective view controller.
3. When i need to show any view controller that is inside my UITableViewController programatically, i simply set a flag and push my UITableViewController, and in viewDidAppear method of my UITableViewController push desired view controller.
4. This will also show back button on programatically opened view to list of MoreViewController